# Nested subdomain URL rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, canonical-link

I have a sight that is of the following form:

```
nested_subdomain1.nested_subdomain2.domain.com
```

It might be something like *test.users.domain.com* and I would like to be able to rewrite this URL to something like *test.users.domain2.com*.

So far, my luck has not proven well and I have not been able to successfully implement a working solution from examples found online.  I have tried some things like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or this one...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^fully\.qualified\.domain\.name$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://fully.qualified.domain.name/$1 [L,R]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and feel like I am missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
#match anything1.anything2.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
#redirect to anything1.anything2.domain2.com
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$
RewriteRule (*.).mydomain.com mydomain.com/$1
```

This will trasnfer xx.yy.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/xx.yy

To replace with slashes, try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$
RewriteRule (*.\.).mydomain.com mydomain.com/$1/$2/$3
```

To transfer to another domain ,try

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.com$
RewriteRule (*.).mydomain.com $1.mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

This will transfer the subdomains upto a level of three. Frankly, you will have to analyze the host in your index.php to determine which subdomain is caled, so might as well use the first one

Comment: thanks for the ideas.  Is there a way to do this so that xx.yy.domain.com becomes xx.yy.domain2.com ?

Comment: not sure. since I generally use Zend or something to care of this. I'll suggest a solution see if it works